# How to make a WHERE clause with date time intervals in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

I have a requirement to retrieve result rows (from yesterday 3 pm to today 3 pm) each row has  the `DateTime` column (timestamp).

how can I query this?

**I prefer codeigniter active records**

Comment: you dont give neither table structure nor even names. what do you expect?  How to make a WHERE clause with date time intervels in Postgresql?
more or less this way: `select columns from table where timestamp_column between timestamp and other_timestamp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$this->db->where('`DateTime` BETWEEN "'. strtotime("yesterday 15:00"). '" and "'. strtotime("today 15:00").'"');
```

Use the PHP function [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) to convert a textual date into a UNIX timestamp, and then use it to compare. Something like `strtotime("yesterday 3pm")` and `strtotime("today 3pm")` should also work. Be aware that unexpected results can depend on different time settings and locale in your database compared to the locale and installation setting on your server and PHP configuration.

If your timestamp is not a Unix Timestamp, you could try the following two alternatives:

```
$this->db->where("`DateTime` BETWEEN '". date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("yesterday 3pm")) ."'::timestamp AND '". date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("today 3pm"))."'::timestamp");
```

OR:

```
$this->db->where("`DateTime` BETWEEN '". date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("yesterday 3pm")) ."' AND '". date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("today 3pm"))."'");
```

Thanks to @Oto and @pozs discussion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42995550/1363190), an even simpler and better approach would be to use native postgresql syntax to compare timestamps:

```
$this->db->where("`DateTime` BETWEEN (current_date - 1) + time '15:00:00' AND current_date + time '15:00:00'");
```

**EDIT**: Note that if your column are named `datetime`you need to put backticks to not confuse with PHP:s datetime-function. Updated the example.

**UPDATE**: Added alternative syntax if you are not using a Unix Timestamp. And a third example using native postgresql syntax for comparing timestamps.

Comment: tried this,,, getting error  `Message: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "1490277600" does not exist LINE 5: AND "DateTime" BETWEEN "1490277600" and "1490364000" ^`

Comment: Is your column named `datetime`? It could because the name is the same as the php function datetime. If so, then try backticks on your filed name like \`datetime\`

Comment: it's DateTime.. also tried with other name..still error!!

Comment: Maybe you are not storing the date as a Unix Timestamp? Updated my answer with two alternatives to try if using native timestamp in postgresql

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about codeigniter active records, for "pure" postgres, you can use this one:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable 
WHERE datetime BETWEEN
to_timestamp ((CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 day')::date||' 15:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
AND
to_timestamp (CURRENT_DATE ||' 15:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: You could use `(current_date - 1) + time '15:00:00'` and `current_date + time '15:00:00'` to avoid unnecessary castings.

Comment: @pozs `current_date + time '15:00:00'` here casting happens anyway , just internally. it's not?

Comment: not exactly, there is an explicit operator `date + time`, which results in `timestamp`. Also, `date +- int` results in `date` (where `int` is the number of days). No casting involved (and neither the `to_timestamp` call with long format strings is needed).